# API Design: Is it a good practice to have an endpoint per action?

Tags: api, api-design, software-design

Let's say we have an API for an e-commerce site. This API has the common endpoints for `/orders`:

```
POST /orders
GET /orders
GET /orders/{orderID}
PUT /orders/{orderID}
DELETE /orders/{orderID}
```

The order entity has a `status` field to indicate the order's status (new, paid, cancelled, etc).

Now, while processing an order we have actions such as pay an order, cancel an order, delete an order etc.

My question is: all these actions might be a simple update to the order's status field which we could perform via `PUT /orders/{orderID}` (or `PATCH`, irrelevant at the moment), is it a better design to have separate endpoints for these actions? Endpoints such as:

```
POST /orders/{orderID}/pay
POST /orders/{orderID}/cancel
POST /orders/{orderID}/ship
```

if not, then why not? are the elements after an ID reserved for relationships only?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you like to implement some form of authorization where different actions require different roles/claims I would prefer the second option.

There you could create one controller for one action and check for roles/claims by annotation if supported by your language, while in your first option the authorization check needs to be done depending on the updated value.

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-6.0) for an .NET 6.0 example.